# Save System.Drawing.Image in a pdf file

Tags: c#, itext

Hello I have a problem with converting a "System.Drawing.Image" into a "iTextSharp.text.Image"
it gives me an error that says "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Drawing.Image to iTextSharp.text.Image"

here is the code if that helps

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace pdf_Generator_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDraw qrcode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.CodeQr;
            System.Drawing.Image qrcodeimage = qrcode.Draw(richTextBox1.Text, 50);
        

            using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "PDF file|*.pdf", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                    try
                    {
                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(richTextBox1.Text));
                        Image jpg = qrcodeimage;
                        doc.Add(jpg);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Messege", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`iTextSharp.text.Document.Add()` does not accept a `System.Drawing.Image`**

It only accepts `iTextSharp.text.Image` classes.

That's easy enough to fix.

```
var itextsharpImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(jpg, null);
doc.Add(itextsharpImg);
```

Pass the `itextsharpImg` to `doc.Add()`, and you should be good to go. The `null` argument is for `baseColor:` if your image has a transparency key (like Windows hot pink bitmaps, or a greenscreen) then you can set that there for opacity in the generated PDF, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for answering but what is jpg; is it  "Image jpg = qrcodeimage;"

Comment: Yup, that's the one :)